# How To Access Two Databases in a Single connection String in C#?

Tags: c#, database

I Need Access for two Different Sql databases Using same Windows Form in VS 2010(c#).

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

//My Code For Connection of one Database named sms. 

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data 
Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\sms.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```

I Also Want to Get Access To This Database with name sms2 in Same Form.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data 
Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\sms2.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```

Thanks For help.

Comment: And what's stopping you? What's the question here? Are you facing some problem? If so, which? What happens? What would you expect instead and why? Please read [ask].

Comment: I've done it!  Go for it.  There is nothing which should stop you from accessing two dbs.  Just use the connection object of the one you want in the places in the code where you need to access the db

Comment: i don't wont to use two connection strings i need the access the two dbs with same connection string so that i can change the db at run time.

Comment: So in your form, let the user decide which DB to connect to. Then pass the string to the connection.

Comment: Yes Sir That is What I Want To do, If user Changed the Database in Combo It need To be Changed in The Form in BackEnd. Please Give me an Example To Pass new String to Connection String.@Aldert. Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use two separate connection objects:

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data 
Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\sms.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data 
Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\sms2.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```